# python starting batch file containing pause command , throws an exception

Tags: python, batch-file, operating-system

I wrote simple python script which starts (`os.start(path)`) a batch file and waits for it to finish by  `os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT,bat,())`.

the problem is that it throws an exception:

"exceptions.EOFError:[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

The script is running on windows 7 64bit and the batch file contains on simple command like cd..

code:

```
import os
bat = r'C:\new folder\start.bat'
os.spawnv(os.P_WAIT,bat,())
print "ok"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: use the subprocess module instead. arguments will be passed directly to the program without shell intervention when using `spawnv`

Comment: thanks for your comment.
can you give an example?

Comment: @Munirn: `subprocess.call(r'C:\new folder\start.bat')`.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters .
i used subprocess.call but the script doesn't open batch file and it didn't end , i track the running code, in subprocess module it stuck in INIFINITE:

def wait(self):
            """Wait for child process to terminate.  Returns returncode
            attribute."""
            if self.returncode is None:
                _subprocess.WaitForSingleObject(self._handle,
                                                _subprocess.INFINITE)
                self.returncode = _subprocess.GetExitCodeProcess(self._handle)
            return self.returncode

Comment: pause will ask for a key, so it may interrupt the output flow, without finsihing, maybe triggering the Exception you mentioned.     If you remove the pause, does it work ?

Comment: nope, its not working without it too...
and as i mention , subprocess.call(path) doesn't open the batch file at all.

Answer (score 1):

To run a batch file on Windows you actually have to `os.spawn()` or `subprocess.call()` something with arguments to simulate a command-line similar to the following:

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\new folder\start.bat"
```

The `/c` argument to `cmd.exe` tells it to execute the supplied command and exit. You'll also need to put double quotes around any paths that contain embedded space characters as shown above.